# How to connect Azure WebApp to an existing vnet using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure

I have followed the instructions at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet/ to connect an Azure WebApp to an existing virtual network and it works great. I would like to do this through powershell so I can automate this along with the rest of my deployment scheme. I have looked into the powershell commands 'New-AzureWebApp', 'New-AzureAppServicePlan' but don't see any option to specify a virtual network and a subnet.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use 
`Set-AzureVNetConfig` to replace your whole vnet configuration if needed
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495195.aspx

edit your `ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg` file for your cloud service
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee758710.aspx

realeted is `NetworkConfiguration` part
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj156091.aspx